# References for trascendental number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm an undergraduate student in Mathematics who has to do a short essay about very **basic** Trascendental Number theory. In particular, I have to study the proof of trascendence of $e$ and $\pi$, and I was looking for some more advanced theorem to study: unfortunately all the material I find is too advanced/requires too much knowledge about analytic number theory. 
Do you know some introductive book about this subject/some -not too difficult- result I can study?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Niven, [Numbers: rational and irrational](https://books.google.ca/books?id=w0VWAQAACAAJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The book https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Transcendental_Numbers.html?id=-4jkAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y, where some of the proofs are readable directly and appear to be elementary.
2. Notes at http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~urops/Projects/transcendental.pdf
   for transcendence of $\pi$.
3. Notes at http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m400su06/transcendence%20of%20e.pdf
   for transcendence of $e$.
4. Notes of Kannan Soundararajan for both at http://math.stanford.edu/~ksound/TransNotes.pdf covers the two proofs on pages 3 and 4.

Comment: Link to 2 is broken; would you happen to remember a title, or have some other way to find it?

Comment: Not that particular one, but here's another link: https://sixthform.info/maths/files/pitrans.pdf